# RavenDB - Disaster Recovery on a Replicated Instance

Tags: document-oriented, disaster-recovery

**EDIT:** I'm encountering precisely [the same issue](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/6aA2jkoz8g4/Sxruy7VKCIMJ).

- Assume that I have two RavenDB instances.
- Instance 1 contains one document: users/1.
- Instance 2 contains three documents: users/2, users/3, and users/4.

_

- Assume that I configure and enable replication for both instances.

  - That is, Instance 1 will replicate to Instance 2 and Instance 2 will replicate to Instance 1.
- After replication, both instances will have all four documents.

  - But both instances will agree that users/1 's `Raven-Replication-Source` is Instance 1, and users/2, users/3, and users/4 will have their `Raven-Replication-Source` set to Instance 2.

_

- Assume that Instance 1 suffers a catastrophic failure and I need to reinstall RavenDB.

_

- My testing shows that in this scenario: users/2, users/3, and users/4 will again be replicated to Instance 1.
- *However*, users/1 will **not** be replicated to Instance 1 because its `Raven-Replication-Source` **is** Instance 1.

---

My Question:

- How can I force Instance 2 to replicate users/1 back to Instance 1, even though users/1 was originally created on Instance 1 and its `Raven-Replication-Source` **is** Instance 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure replication as ['Changed and Replicated'](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ravendb/6aA2jkoz8g4/7wKslzbFWaoJ).